# Moving imageview in a circular motion in android

Tags: java, android

I want to translate a view in a circular motion, based on values from both the x and y axis touch event.

I got it to work using only one axis, as seen in the gif below.

[image]

The site trumpdonald.org have the exact motion i'm looking for.

You can move the mouse freely around the screen, and the trumpet follows the mouse, but it stays in the circular path.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            rawScreenX = event.getRawX();
            rawScreenY = event.getRawY();

            int radius = 500;

            //change the range from screenwidth/height into 2*PI 
            float x = changeRange(0, screenWidth, 0,2*(float)Math.PI, rawScreenX);
            float y = changeRange(0, screenHeight, 0,2*(float)Math.PI, rawScreenY);

            double yTranslate = radius * Math.sin(x);
            double xTranslate = radius * Math.cos(x);


            imageView.setTranslationY((float) yTranslate);
            imageView.setTranslationX((float) xTranslate);



            return true;
        }
```

Comment: imageView.animate().rotation(180).start(); ?

Comment: i don't want to rotate the image, i want it to follow a circular path

Answer (score 5):

You can try this..

```
//@image - imageView, @float - radius
Animation anim = new CircularRotateAnimation(image, 500);
//duration of animation
anim.setDuration(3000);
//start the animation
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

Create a custom animation class

```
public class CircularRotateAnimation extends Animation {

    private View view;              // view you want to animate
    private float cx, cy;           // center x,y position of circular path
    private float prevX, prevY;     // previous x,y position of image during animation
    private float r;                // radius of circle
    private float prevDx, prevDy;


    /**
     * @param view - View that will be animated
     * @param r - radius of circular path
     */
    public CircularRotateAnimation(View view, float r){
        this.view = view;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        // calculate position of image center
        int cxImage = width / 2;
        int cyImage = height / 2;
        cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
        cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

        // set previous position to center
        prevX = cx;
        prevY = cy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if(interpolatedTime == 0){
            t.getMatrix().setTranslate(prevDx, prevDy);
            return;
        }

        float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;
        float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

        // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
        float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
        float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));


        float dx = prevX - x;
        float dy = prevY - y;

        prevX = x;
        prevY = y;

        prevDx = dx;
        prevDy = dy;

        //applying the circular animation
        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
    }
}
```

Override onTouch function to detect action_move

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                //your calculation;
                rawScreenX = event.getRawX();
                rawScreenY = event.getRawY();

                //modify CirculateRotateAnimation function accroding to your needs

                Animation anim = new CircularRotateAnimation(image, YOUR CALCULATED RADIUS);
                anim.setDuration(YOUR TIMING);
                image.startAnimation(anim);

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but I need the view to move following my finger on the screen, but in a circular path. just like the website i linked to in my question: trumpdonald.org

Comment: I can't work to your onTouch function in that animation. I have to click images when animation is playing. But when I click images, onTouch doesn't work. Can you help me?